# Numpy Remove duplicates, apply function, then add it back

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

We have an array `x` containing duplicates and a function `f()` that only accepts a 1-D array without duplicates. We need the results of `f(x)` as if the function can accept duplicate values.

If we had removed the duplicate values before passing it into the function, how can we add duplicated results to the array return by the function?

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    ''' assume this function cannot accept duplicates '''
    return -1 * x

x = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 11, 13, 13, 15, 17, 17, 19, 21, 21, 21, 23])
y = f(np.unique(x))

print(y)    # [ -1 -3 -5 -7 -9 -11 -13 -15 -17 -19 -21 -23 

# Needed: [ -1 -3 -5 -7 -7 -9 -9 -9 -11 -13 -13 -15 -17 -17 -19 -21 -21 -21 -23 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Use [`return_inverse`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) argument with it -

```
unq, tags  = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
out = f(unq)[tags]
```

**Approach #2**

We can skip the sorting with `np.unique` using `pandas.factorize` instead for perf. boost -

```
import pandas as pd

tags, unq = pd.factorize(x)
out = f(unq)[tags]
```

Assumption is that `f` is working on an elementwise-manner.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit strange...

```
import numpy as np

def f(X):
    return -1 * x

x = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 11, 13, 13, 15, 17, 17, 19, 21, 21, 21, 23])
y = f(np.unique(x))

print(y)
```

Output:

```
[ -1  -3  -5  -7  -7  -9  -9  -9 -11 -13 -13 -15 -17 -17 -19 -21 -21 -21 -23]
```

Comment: I am not getting that `y`. Are you sure you printing the `y` from your code?

Comment: Yes. Try copying and pasting the whole thing.

Comment: Your `f` has wrong syntax. It should be `def f(x):`. There's typo.

Comment: You have `def f(X):`. Why are using `x` and not `X` inside the function?

Comment: So it can return x without removal of duplicates.

Comment: I will give it a last try to correct your typo - It should be `def f(x)`, not `def f(X)`. Wrong posts bother me, hence trying to correct this one.

Comment: If I change `def f(X)` to `def f(x)`, the program will not work as intended anymore.

Comment: With `def f(X): return -1 * x`, it's picking `x` from globals(), not the function argument, which has `X`. I am assuming you are noticing the difference between `X` and `x`. `f(np.unique(x))` is not supposed to work as OP showed in the question. Making a typo just to show an expected output isn't a solution.

Comment: what makes it a typo?

Comment: `return -1 * x` is using `x`, while function definition `def f(X)` has `X`. So, it should be `def f(x)`. Does that make sense?